# UI elements on iPhone 6 Plus don't fill the whole screen horizontally

Tags: ios, iphone, uistoryboard, iphone-6-plus

When developing for iPhone 6 Plus (all others devices are unaffected). If you have a UI element that is suppose to fill the screen horizontally from one end to the other, the leading and trailing constraints are usually -16, since the 0 is assumed to be 16 points from the margin.

This looks fine on storyboard and on all devices except iPhone 6 Plus (both physical device and simulator).

As you can see here, the definitions I have for this test view on storyboard:

[image]

On iPhone 6 Plus this is what I get:

[image]

There are clearly some non filled border left and right of that black view.
I did some tests with setting the constraints to -19 and -20 to see if the space would be filled:

[image]

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

On the left, where the constraint is -20 there is no border, and on the right where the constraint is -19, there is a 1 pixel border.

My conclusion is that the 0 point on iPhone 6 Plus is 20 points away from the margin instead of 16 as in all other devices. This can't be intended, it's clearly an iOS bug.

Has anyone faced this issue? Is there a workaround to make this consistent, so that I don't have to add hardcoded exceptions for iPhone 6 Plus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use margin. You have the option of turning the margin off on your constraints.

The point of a margin is that it is controlled by the system, not you, so it can be set to an appropriate size for each device. And it makes sense for the margin to be a little bigger on larger devices than small ones.

Comment: Where exactly do I disable the margins? Is there a storyboard wide option or is it per constraint?

Comment: It is everywhere, do i have to turn off everywhere? or there is another work around

Comment: I think you need to do it individually, I'm not aware of a global setting unfortunately